# no transaction is in progress in Spring MVC with JPA and Spring 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-3

I can't persist data in the db using the injected entitymgr in spring mvc. I've try with a lot of similar questions, but none of the answers seem to solve my issue.

I have a config like:
applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="...">
<import resource="config-context.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springbyexample.orm.jpa.inheritance.dao" />
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">  
        <property name="transactionInterceptor" ref="transactionInterceptorIkConf"/>
        <property name="classFilter">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.TypePatternClassFilter">  
                <constructor-arg value="com.package..*"></constructor-arg>  
            </bean>
        </property>               
</bean>

<bean id="transactionInterceptorIkConf"  
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">  
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>  
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>  
        </property>  
</bean> 

</beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="...">
<import resource="config-context.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springbyexample.orm.jpa.inheritance.dao" />
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">  
        <property name="transactionInterceptor" ref="transactionInterceptorIkConf"/>
        <property name="classFilter">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.TypePatternClassFilter">  
                <constructor-arg value="com.package..*"></constructor-arg>  
            </bean>
        </property>               
</bean>

<bean id="transactionInterceptorIkConf"  
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">  
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>  
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>  
        </property>  
</bean> 

</beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="...">
<import resource="config-context.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springbyexample.orm.jpa.inheritance.dao" />
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">  
        <property name="transactionInterceptor" ref="transactionInterceptorIkConf"/>
        <property name="classFilter">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.TypePatternClassFilter">  
                <constructor-arg value="com.package..*"></constructor-arg>  
            </bean>
        </property>               
</bean>

<bean id="transactionInterceptorIkConf"  
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">  
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>  
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>  
        </property>  
</bean> 

</beans>
```

in config-context.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

<context:property-placeholder location="..." 
        ignore-unresolvable="true" order="1" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>       
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"                                    
        order="2"/> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.package" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*controller\.[^.]*"/>
</context:component-scan>

<!-- Handler for serving static content -->      
<bean id="ikconfStaticResources" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/META-INF/resources/static/</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="conf-persistence"/>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="ikconfDataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ikusi.ikconf" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaDialect">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />      
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>            
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>            
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ikconfDataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="emf" autowire="byName"/>

</beans>
```

in mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.package" >
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*controller\.[^.]*"/>
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

inside web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>

<display-name>demo-app</display-name>

<!-- Spring context -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfiglocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Now I have one controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private OneService service; //with getters and setters

    @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody Data move(@RequestBody Data data) {
        getService().doSomething(data);
    }
}
```

and a service

```
@Service
public class OneService {
    @Autowired
    private OneDao dao;


    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = { IkfBusinessException.class })
    public void doSomething(Data data) {
        //Do the actual logic inside transaction
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "conf-persistence")
    @Override
    protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

I'm having this error: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress when I'm calling the service from my controller.

But when I run it with a Bootstrap class it works properly.

I think I have something wrong with my MVC config.

Comment: You are scanning for the same comopnents twice rendering your `@Transactional` use less. In your mvc context add `use-default-filters="false"` to your `<component-scan />`. The include doesn't mean everything else (`scanning for `@Component` and other annotations gets disabled).

Comment: First of all thanks. I'm trying your advise with no resuts. Could you please extend a little bit more? Maybe I'm missunderstanding. Thanks

Comment: If I add use-default-filters="false" to my mvc context My controller is not working, no page is rendered.

Comment: Assuming you are using `@Controller` I suggest using a `annotation` expression instead of a `regexp`. `<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>` also note that you are basically detecting your controllers twice (once in the root and once in the servlet).

Answer (score 1):

I have one possible sollution:

I change my component scan inside mvc-servlet like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.controller"/>
```

To add only my controllers, since "context:include-filter" doesn't include exclusively indicated packages.

With this config it's working now. Maybe there is a better config.

Anyway thanks you all for your time, and if you have any more suggestions you can reply.

Thanks